# Работа с вектором обьектов класса С++

Tags: c++, vector

Написал курсовую, оказалось, что сделал не так. Хранил данные в виде

```
    vector<string>last_name;//фамилия
    vector<string>first_name;//имя
    vector<string>middle_name;//отчество
    vector<int>age;//возраст
    vector<string>street;//улица
    vector<string>house;//дом
```

Выполнял добавление, удаление, редактирование, поиск и т.д. данных. Путем работы с файлом.

Теперь мне нужно понять, как работать с данными через вектор объектов, а не то недоразумение выше.
Как добавлять и выводить данные? Прошу ссылку или пример кода. Именно добавление данных в файл и просмотр данных с файла путем записи данных в переменные. С остальным сам разберусь.
Спасибо!!!

Comment: Прежде чем работать с вектором объектов нужно сначала определить структуру объекта (класс или структура)

Comment: Да это я понимаю, но я не пойму, как это работает, мне просто нужен пример

Comment: возьмите любой учебник по c++ и почитайте

Comment: Ладно, я понял, просто время поджимает, спасибо